# trouble in sending data through ajax to express server

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, express

I'm new to `backend` and I was having some trouble in sending data through vanilla ajax to my express server.
please tell me where am I going wrong

my ajax request:

```
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onload = function() {
   
};
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080", true);
  xhttp.withCredentials = true;
  xhttp.send("name=abhishek");
```

my express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');


var app = express();
app.use(cors({
    credentials:true,
    origin:'http://127.0.0.1:5500'
}));
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.query);
            
});

app.listen(PORT, function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

I'm receiving an empty object as the output in my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to change.

The client is a POST request but in server side, it is a GET `app.get()`. Therefore, nothing displayed after request.
Also, `Content-type` needs to be set to inform server how it is going to parse the message. e.g. JSON/form-data

I assume you want to use POST, below is the change:

Backend:

- Change method from `app.get` to `app.post`
- Get the data from `body` instead of `query`

```
...
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // data is in body instead of query
  res.send("hi"); // send back response to frontend
});
...
```

Frontend:

- Set content-type

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
  alert(xhttp.responseText); // should receive hi
};

xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.send("name=abhishek");
```